# Silent casting invalid bool values from table

Tags: specflow

When parsing a table with bool values, I get a silent conversion to `false` for values that can't logically be parsed.
Using the following step:

```
When I send a POST HTTP request to store/order with very bad data
| complete |
| nope     |
```

With

```
[When(@"I send a POST HTTP request to store/order with very bad data")]
public void WhenISendAPOSTHTTPRequestToStoreOrderWithVeryBadData(Table table)
{
    var orderTable = table.CreateInstance<(bool Complete)>();

    Console.WriteLine($"complete: {orderTable.Complete}");
    ...
}
```

Will result in

```
complete: false
```

I'm expecting the table conversion to throw an error rather than the more python-like behavior. Can I toggle hard type checks somehow?

And is it possible to toggle parser behavior so the table is read as all strings? That way I could create JSON data for negative testing using the same step. Alternative suggestions to reusing steps for negative data testing, would also be appreciated.

Comment: Tables in specflow are strings by default. The `table` parameter provides an API allowing you to access the raw string values in each cell in each row.

Comment: Interesting. How do i then inject myself between the string representation and final object result, so I could get a runtime cast error?

Comment: Simply put: you can't.